# admin-on-rest / restClient : call a resource with no auth

Tags: admin-on-rest

I made a register page that use restClient to send a POST to /users api.
But my problem is that the only way to send a POST is to be logged first as I receive this error log from the restClient :

> 'Could not find stored JWT and no authentication strategy was given'

Is there a way to desactivate the authentication middleware for a specific api call ?

```js
// registerActions.js
import { CREATE } from 'admin-on-rest'

export const USER_REGISTER = 'AOR/USER_REGISTER'
export const USER_REGISTER_LOADING = 'AOR/USER_REGISTER_LOADING'
export const USER_REGISTER_FAILURE = 'AOR/USER_REGISTER_FAILURE'
export const USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS = 'AOR/USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS'

export const userRegister = (data, basePath) => ({
    type: USER_REGISTER,
    payload: { data: { email: data.username, ...data } },
    meta: { resource: 'users', fetch: CREATE, auth: true },
})

//registerSaga.js
import { put, takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { showNotification } from 'admin-on-rest'

import {
    USER_REGISTER,
    USER_REGISTER_LOADING,
    USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    USER_REGISTER_FAILURE
} from './registerActions'

function* registerSuccess() {
    yield put(showNotification('Register approved'))
    yield put(push('/'))
}

function* registerFailure({ error }) {
    yield put(showNotification('Error: register not approved', 'warning'))
    console.error(error)
}

export default function* commentSaga() {
    yield all([
      takeEvery(USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, registerSuccess),
      takeEvery(USER_REGISTER_FAILURE, registerFailure),
    ])
}
```

Comment: We need to see your restClient

Comment: I'm using "aor-feathers-client": "^0.6.0",

Comment: You can see the source here : https://github.com/josx/aor-feathers-client/blob/master/src/restClient.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to make your own feathers client and explicitly bypass the call to [authenticate](https://github.com/josx/aor-feathers-client/blob/master/src/restClient.js#L89) for this specific request

Comment: Thx, It looks to be my only option for now. I'll propose a PR to the project for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a rest wrappper this will intercept the call for this particular case and bypass auth

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

So something like below

```
const restWrapper = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
import { fetchUtils } from 'admin-on-rest';

if (type === 'CREATE' && resource === 'users') {
       return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, params)
          .then((response) => {
           const {json} = response;
           return { data: json };
})


}
```

Eliminates the need of rewriting an entire Rest Client when you only want to override the default behaviour for a single case

Comment: I was not sure it was possible, how can I prevent auth check for a specific api call in your exemple ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Feathers but I am assuming you have to attach a authorisation header etc. Which you RestClient is checking for and cannot find. In the restWrapper above you can simply call the URL with the data just input by the user.